# Get data, change one single element and return to api

Tags: angularjs, forms, radio-button

I get Data from an api and easily list them, now i want to change one element of those, to "default". I dont know how to control that,

Here is the js.

```
    $scope.updateDefault = function() {
                if (AuthService.isAuth()) {

                    Account.one().get().then(
                            function(account) {

                              **account.data.defaultMsisdn= $scope.element.isSelected;
                                $log.d("account: ", account.data);
                                account.data.put();**
                            }
                    );
                }
            };
```

here is the HTML:

```
     <div id="container" style="width:650px">
    <ol ng-repeat="element in accountmsisdn">

        **<li style=" text-align:left; float:left">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="element.isSelected" ng-click="updateDefault()">
            <span>{{element.msisdn}} </span>
        </li>**
        <li style="text-align:center;float: inside" ng-switch="element.active">
            <span ng-switch-when=true>
                {{'view.settings.sender.active'| translate}}</span>
            <span ng-switch-when=false>
                {{'view.settings.sender.notactive'| translate}}</span>
            <span ng-switch-default>
                <strong> - </strong> </span>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the current `element` as an argument to `updateDefault()`, so it knows what element to update:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="element.isSelected" ng-click="updateDefault(element)" />

$scope.updateDefault = function (element) {
    ...
    account.data.defaultMsisdn = element.isSelected;
    ..
};
```

Comment: i get this error when doing this   @ put   error 500
{"statusMessage":"Internal server error","property":null,"url":null,"nested":null,"status":"INTERNAL_ERROR","statusCode":5000}

Comment: @Flowdo: I can't really tell what causes the error, since I don't have a way to reproduce your problem or your setup. The first question is: Is `account.data` what you expect it to be, before calling `account.data.put()` ?

Comment: The problem was right this, account.data was broken, but i dont know why- i begin to search the reason for that, after your helpful advice.  Thank you.